# Store a jquery value in a php variable

Tags: php, ajax

The button of the modal contains the post id:

`<button onclick='getValue("<?=$id?>");' data-toggle="modal" name="submit" data-target="#squarespaceModal">Purchase  Now</button>`

When I use `alert` it shows this id properly, but I need to store this id in a **PHP** variable

```
              `function getValue(id){
                       alert(id);
                  // i am trying this but not done
                 // <?php $xyz = ?> id ;

                }`
```

I am also trying to use `$.post` but in a modal the data is not coming
like

`$.post( "<?=$current_url;?>", function( id ) {
                             // $( "#div1" ).html( id );
                             //alert(id);
                            });`

How can i **store a jquery value in a php variable**? Most of the examples I have seen work the other way around, like `var x =<?php echo $y;?>`, but I need the opposite.

Comment: What result did you get from `alert(id);`?

Comment: my post id like 1 / 2

Comment: i just want this  id in any php variable

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it using jQuery alone; you'll need a combination of Ajax and PHP file. For example:
**HTML**

```
<button onclick='getValue("<?=$id?>");' data-toggle="modal" name="submit" data-target="#squarespaceModal">Purchase  Now</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
function getValue(id) {
        // Send Ajax request to ajax_file.php, with id as POST data
        $.post("ajax_file.php", {'id': id}, function(result){ alert(result)});
 }
```

**ajax_file.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
       $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
       echo $_SESSION['id'];
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <Script>
 getValue(5);
 function getValue(id){ 
alert(id);
// i am trying this but not done
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: {id:id},
url: "http://localhost/key/index2.php/",
success: function(data){
alert(data);

}
});

}
 </script>

in index2.php

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['id']=$_POST['id'];
echo $_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

here i had made ajax call to php file and in that file,i had stored sent id in session,so now you had that id in php variable in session

Comment: thank you Sonia, ajax alert are coming but php post data are not coming the session data are not coming

Comment: <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
 echo $_SESSION['id'];
}?>write this code in php file where you want to print session stored id,write this code at the top of the file